# Write a query to display the sales id, sales date, price and discount of the mobile. If the discount is not available display "Not Applicable"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing this query: `SELECT salesid, sales_date, price, nvl2(discount, discount, 'Not Applicable')`, but it is showing error as `ORA-01722: invalid number`

[image: Database schema]

Comment: Seeing as you're using Oracle, why not tag Oracle instead of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Can we try this?

```
CASE WHEN DISCOUNT IS NOT NULL THEN DISCOUNT ELSE "NOT APPLICABLE" END
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want the expression to return a string.  So, you need to convert the number to a string for this to work:

```
SELECT salesid, sales_date, price,
       coalesce(to_char(discount), 'Not Applicable')
```